# extract "component-scan" value from spring

Tags: spring, configuration

i am trying to implement a dynamic facility extension to spring framework. i need 
context:component-scan values. for example how do i extract "org.inanme.mock.easymock" value?
Although this example is very simple, but you know it get quite complex.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.inanme.mock.easymock" />
```

i am thinking of implementing "BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor" class, so i have "ConfigurableListableBeanFactory", "BeanDefinitionRegistry" classes. Do they have above information? or what else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source for [ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.context/3.0.4/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java) it doesn't look like that value is saved anywhere where it is retrievable.  The alternative is to parse the context XML yourself and extract it.

Comment: agree ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser does not expose after reading.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the base-package attribute value, or it would be enough for you to know all the matched beans? For the latter, you might just try to scan the application context for beans annotated with `@Component` or derived annotations.

Comment: not interested in existing matched beans. i was trying to find a neat way of defining new beans dynamically before configuration freezes.